# How to navigate to another page by making <View> container clickable in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I needed custom shaped button so I used `<View>` and designed the button the way I need with `<Image>` and `<Text>` the problem I am facing here is I need that custom `<View>` button to be clickable to that after clicking on that I can redirect to another page.

**Code for button**

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Text style={styles.headerfont}>Categories</Text>
  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, left: 195 }}>View More</Text>
    <Image
      style={{ left: 200, height: 23, width: 23 }}
      source={require('../img/agni/viewmore.png')}
    />
  </View>
</View>;
```

**Things I have tried**

- `<Pressable>`
- `<TouchableOpacity>`

**Image Representation**

After clicking should redirect from Screen 1 to Screen 2

[image]

Comment: You could just add an onClick() function to the View tag. Though you'd probably want to style the hover and pressed states, so that it gives feedback like a normal button would. The element should be clickable, but it's hard to tell without styling those states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create navigator for pages we need to navigate through.
Use TouchableOpacity for onPress for pushing page.

**App.js**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="AgniViewMorePage" component={AgniViewMorePage} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation}) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text>Categories</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, left: 195 }}>View More</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

**Profile.js**

```
export default function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Go to Notifications"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        />
        <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native by default does support routing, you'll need to build on your own, luckily there is **react-navigation**, which aims to create routing and navigation for Expo and React Native apps.

See their website here https://reactnavigation.org

---

In order to create a clickable view on React Native, you'll need a TouchableOpacity.

```js
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default () => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('Do something')}>
    <View>
       <Text>Example</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Another option would be Button

```js
<Button title="Click Me" onPress={() => console.log('Do something')} />
```

and here is a quick demo to move between screens:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Home"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is a snack https://snack.expo.dev/@abranhe/hello-react-navigation

Comment: How can you link another page on onPress={() => console.log(****HERE****)}>

Comment: See the example below that:  `navigation.navigate('Details')`